# trying to plot two groups on the same figure using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have my data like this

```
Name    group   median  SD
First   Mydate  12.118  2.221
First   Best1   18.806  0.721
First   Best2   22.670  0.092
Second  Mydate  22.911  0.322
Second  Best1   23.495  0.756
Second  Best2   23.028  0.685
```

I am trying to plot both on the same figures (First and Second name)

when I do this

```
gplot(mydf, aes(x = group, y = median, color=group))+
  geom_point(size = 3)
```

it plot the dots

but when I want to make the line and I add this

```
+ geom_line(color = "black",linetype="dashed", group = 1)
```

it plot all dots as line

basically I want to plot it with SD like this

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = group, y = median, color=group))+
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_line(color = "black",linetype="dashed", group = 2)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = median - SD, ymax = median + SD), colour = c("Blue", "Red","green"))
```

but two groups on the same figure

after so much attempt, I somehow figured that I could plot it like this but still cannot assign the SD to each

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = group, y = median, color=Name)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line(data=mytt[mytt$Name!="First", ]) +
    scale_color_manual("Dataset", 
                       values = c("First" = "darkgreen", "Second" = "blue"))
```

Comment: @jared_mamrot If I knew how to solve the problem, I would not ask here, I posted a new way to see the data, basically I have two line plots on the same figure and I am trying to assign the SD to each of them

Comment: Yes, of course, I'm just trying to work out how to help you. do you want the line to join the same "Name" dots? Or the "group" dots? Is my answer below close to what you're after @nik?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your expected outcome?

```r
library(ggplot2)

mydf <- read.table(text = "Name    group   median  SD
First   Mydate  12.118  2.221
First   Best1   18.806  0.721
First   Best2   22.670  0.092
Second  Mydate  22.911  0.322
Second  Best1   23.495  0.756
Second  Best2   23.028  0.685", header = TRUE)

mydf
#>     Name  group median    SD
#> 1  First Mydate 12.118 2.221
#> 2  First  Best1 18.806 0.721
#> 3  First  Best2 22.670 0.092
#> 4 Second Mydate 22.911 0.322
#> 5 Second  Best1 23.495 0.756
#> 6 Second  Best2 23.028 0.685

ggplot(mydf, aes(x = group, y = median, color = group)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Name), color = "black", linetype="dashed") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = median - SD, ymax = median + SD))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Yes yes , one more thing and I accept and like your answer, do you think it is possible to change the color of Best 1 the same , Best 2 the same and mydate the same?

Comment: Ahh - sorry I misunderstood before - I'll edit my answer to colour points/errorbars by Best 1 / Best 2 / Mydate

Comment: thanks a lot, I am wondering if there is a way to add significant to the figure ? I can ask another question though like p value ***

Comment: I tried to add p-values to the plot but wasn't able to do it sorry. I think the best thing would be to ask a new question and see if someone else can help.